# CodeIgniter loading a view through controller from another view

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

For Security reasons as mentioned here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html I have placed the system and application folders in another folder called OSW_appnsys, which is above the web root folder. Now I have a controller class called 'Pages' and a 'View' function in it in the following directory.

```
C:\wamp\www\OSW_appnsys\application\controllers
```

Now when I am calling the 'View' method of the controller 'Pages' from another view file called 'header.php' I am getting the 404 error like this

```
The requested URL /CodeIgniter_2.1.2/pages/view/products was not found on this server.
```

where product is the URI.

And I am calling this way:

```
<a class="mainmenu" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/products')?>">Products</a>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Ty

Comment: and if I directly access the controller class through the complete directory link then I get the error "Forbidden. You dont have the permission to access application folder"

Comment: if view is the method what is products the parameters to your method ?

Comment: products is the name of a view file products.php

Comment: Did you do this step from documentation: `After moving them, open your main index.php file and set the $system_folder and $application_folder variables, preferably with a full path, e.g. '/www/MyUser/system'.` ?

Comment: we dont traditionally load views like this 
we would call the controller function pages/views and then 
    $this->load->view('products');

Comment: @user1537158 I have dont exactly the same way you are telling. but the server cannot find the controller file that is 'pages'

Comment: Did you set the `$config['base_url']` variable in `/application/config`? How does your .`htaccess` file look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't link to a view, you link to the name of a controller. If your controller is named 'Pages', you have to link to:

```
<a class="mainmenu" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/controllers/products')?>">Products</a>
```

Assuming that you have placed your controllers in a 'pages/controllers/' folder. In the controller named 'pages' you load the view (a file named products_view.php or something, which is in your views folder)  like so:

```
$this->load->view('products_view.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have understood how CodeIgniter works.

As above, within your configuration file, you will have

```
$application_folder = 'application';
$system_folder = 'system';
```

Change these to

```
$application_folder = '../OSW_appnsys/application';
$system_folder = '../OSW_appnsys/system';
```

Then point your browser to the URL of where the CodeIgniter's index.php exists.

i.e.

```
\
\OSW_appnsys
\OSW_appnsys\application
\OSW_appnsys\system
\htdocs
\htdocs\index.php
```

via

`http://localhost/index.php`

Also, when accessing controllers or views, you simply need to access the controller name. i.e.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('pages/view'); ?>">Go to page</a>
```

Then you would have a Page controller with a View action within which would do

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view()
    {
        echo $this->load->view('pages/view');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in anchor tag

```
base_url().'index.php/pages/view'
```

and load view `products.php` in view function in Controller

Comment: could you show what you have mentioned $application_folder='' and $system_folder='' in index.php file

Comment: yes , also check your .htaccess , the ReWriteBase that you have specified

Comment: @user1537158 what should i write in that file ? right now its DENY FROM ALL

Comment: for example in index.php 
 $system_path = 'OSW_appnsys/system';
and 
$application_folder = 'OSW_appnsys/application';

if your application and system folder in OSW_appnsys